# How can I use EditText Number Format in Math (Android)?

Tags: android, math, numbers, android-edittext

EditText is "number decimal." I thought it was an integer so I could use numA to square but it shows me an error "Change type of "numA" to 'double'. 
Any help would be great appreciated.

```
EditText numA, numB, numC;
numA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numA);
numB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numB);
numC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numC);
Double sqrt = (Double) (Math.pow(numA, 2));
```

Comment: get text from editText and convert String to double first

Comment: Now just copy paste all code and enjoy and please don't forget to give up vote and green mark to my answer..
I need some point on stackoverflow...

Comment: Hey is it work for you? please give up vote and green mark to my answer.. i spent a lot time for your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please try something like that-

```
 package com.example.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editPsw;
    Button btnCheckBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editPsw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btnCheckBox=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);



        btnCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 Double getText=Double.parseDouble(editPsw.getText().toString());
                    Double sqrt = (Double) (Math.pow(getText, 2));
                    System.out.println(sqrt);

            }
        });
    }



}
```

And in your layout-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yes it will got crash if no value in your edit text so just put these line inside any button..

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the value at first:

```
double a=Double.parseDouble(numA.getText().toString());
```

Your misstake is that you just put in a control, you need also to get the value. That value is a string so you also need to parse it too. That's what I have done in that line of code above.